# How do I substitute based on character and position in word

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-statements, character, substitution

I have one word per cell. I need to substitute characters with other characters based on a range of conditions, as follows.

Condition 1 - if the word contains an 'l' double it to 'll'.
Condition 2 - if the first vowel in the word is an 'e', split the word with an apostrophe after said 'e'.
Condition 3 - the last vowel of each word becomes an 'i'.
Condition 4 - if the word ends in 'a','e','i','o', add an m to the end.

Ideally, I'd like them all to work in one formula, but each working separately would suffice. I can apply in a chain, cell to cell.

Condition 1 - SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(E2,"l","ll"),"L","Ll")
This is successful.

Condition 2 - SUBSTITUTE("e","e'",1)
Applies to every 'e', rather than only when it is the first vowel in the word.

Together, these work as =SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(E2,"l","ll"),"L","Ll"),"e","e'",1)

Condition 3 - NO CURRENT FORMULA

Condition 4 - IF(RIGHT(TRIM(F2),1)="a",F2&"m",F2&"")
Works for a single letter (in this case "a"), but not for all required letters at once.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75173838/edit) your question and insert a [table](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data side-by-side your manually entered desired results. Also consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet. There is a [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) that lets you share safely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `regexreplace()`, like this:

```
=lambda(
  data, regexes, replaceWith, 
  byrow( 
    data, 
    lambda( 
      word, 
      if( 
        len(word), 
        reduce( 
          trim(word), sequence(counta(regexes)), 
          lambda( 
            acc, regexIndex, 
            regexreplace( 
              acc, 
              "(?i)" & index(regexes, regexIndex), 
              index(replaceWith, regexIndex) 
            ) 
          ) 
        ), 
        iferror(1/0)  
      ) 
    ) 
  ) 
)( 
  A2:A10, 
  { "l", "^([^aeiou]*)(e)", "[aeiou]([^aeiou]*)$", "([aeio])$" }, 
  { "ll", "$1e-", "i$1", "$1m" }  
)
```

The formula will only deal with lowercase letters because that is what is specified by the question. To replace uppercase letters as well, prefix the first `index()` with `"(?i)" &` . Note that case will not be retained.